# Different data in upper and lower panel of scatterplot matrix

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I want to plot two different data sets in a [scatterplot matrix](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/pairs.html).

I know that I can use `upper.panel` and `lower.panel` to differentiate the *plot function*. However, I don’t succeed in putting my data in a suitable format to harness this.

Assume I have two tissues (“brain” and “heart”) and four conditions (1–4). Now I can use e.g. `pairs(data$heart)` to get a scatterplot matrix for one of the data sets. Assume I have the following data:

```
conditions <- 1 : 4
noise <- rnorm(100)
data <- list(brain = sapply(conditions, function (x) noise + 0.1 * rnorm(100)),
             heart = sapply(conditions, function (x) noise + 0.3 * rnorm(100)))
```

How do I get this into a format so that `pairs(data, …)` plots one data set above and one below the diagonal, as shown here (green = brain, violet = heart):

[image: screenshot]

Just using

```
pairs(data, upper.panel = something, lower.panel = somethingElse)
```

Doesn’t work because that will plot all conditions versus all conditions without regard for different tissue – it essentially ignores the list, and the same when reordering the hierarchy (i.e. having `data = (A=list(brain=…, heart=…), B=list(brain=…, heart=…), …)`).

Comment: Here's an example of different content in the upper and lower parts, maybe you can adapt it for your needs? http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/Correlation_Matrix_137

Comment: @Ben That example is in the documentation but it doesn’t plot different data, just the same data in a different format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the best I seem to be able to do via passing arguments:

```
foo.upper <- function(x,y,ind.upper,col.upper,ind.lower,col.lower,...){
    points(x[ind.upper],y[ind.upper],col = col.upper,...)
}

foo.lower <- function(x,y,ind.lower,col.lower,ind.upper,col.upper,...){
    points(x[ind.lower],y[ind.lower],col = col.lower,...)
}

pairs(dat[,-5],
        lower.panel = foo.lower,
        upper.panel = foo.upper,
        ind.upper = dat$type == 'brain',
        ind.lower = dat$type == 'heart',
        col.upper = 'blue',
        col.lower = 'red')
```

Note that each panel needs all arguments. `...` is a cruel mistress. If you include only the panel specific arguments in each function, it appears to work, but you get lots and lots of warnings from R trying to pass these arguments on to regular plotting functions and obviously they won't exist.

This was my quick first attempt, but it seems ugly:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,data))
dat$type <- rep(c('brain','heart'),each = 100)

foo.upper <- function(x,y,...){
    points(x[dat$type == 'brain'],y[dat$type == 'brain'],col = 'red',...)
}

foo.lower <- function(x,y,...){
    points(x[dat$type == 'heart'],y[dat$type == 'heart'],col = 'blue',...)
}

pairs(dat[,-5],lower.panel = foo.lower,upper.panel = foo.upper)
```

[image]

I'm abusing R's scoping here in this second version a somewhat ugly way. (Of course, you could probably do this more cleanly in **lattice**, but you probably knew that.)

The only other option I can think of is to design your own scatter plot matrix using `layout`, but that's probably quite a bit of work.

**Lattice Edit**

Here's at least a start on a lattice solution. It *should* handle varying x,y axis ranges better, but I haven't tested that.

```
dat <- do.call(rbind,data)
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
dat$grp <- rep(letters[1:2],each = 100)

plower <- function(x,y,grp,...){
    panel.xyplot(x[grp == 'a'],y[grp == 'a'],col = 'red',...)
}

pupper <- function(x,y,grp,...){
    panel.xyplot(x[grp == 'b'],y[grp == 'b'],...)
}

splom(~dat[,1:4],
        data = dat,
        lower.panel = plower,
        upper.panel = pupper,
        grp = dat$grp)
```

Comment: Very clever use of `...` to pass through `ind.upper` and `ind.lower`! Why not make your (better) revised answer the main one, showing it off up top?

Comment: @JoshOBrien Was rushing out the door to catcha bus. I'll edit when I get home. (And I think I'm wrong about needing all te argumets in each function...)

Comment: Incidentally I really cannot find any way to do this “more cleanly with lattice” – indeed, `lattice` seems to suffer from the same problem but since the documentation isn’t great I’m not actually sure. The above method unfortunately fails if the two data sets have different value ranges (since `pairs` limits the individual cells taking *all* data into account) so I’d be interested in an alternative.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I had a go at a lattice solution. (And I hate reading the lattice documentation as well; I feel like it's as if David Foster Wallace wrote it, or something.)

Comment: @joran Thanks! I have different scales in axes in upper and lower panels. Any thought on how to include these different axes in the figure?